# i'm having trouble with ValueErrors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I'm trying to create a class "Hippocrates" with a function inside that lets me create a dictionary from a given text document (the content of the document is not important to my issue). When I try to return a value from the dictionary and the key does not exist in said dictionary, I want to raise a ValueError stating "invalid ICD-code". I then want the code to continue running since I need it to be able to keep returning values one after each other, but since I raise a ValueError the code stops.

I tried putting it inside a try except block but I'm not too familiar with it yet so I'm struggling.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Hippocrates:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.file = open(location, "r")

    def description(self, code):
        answer = {}
        data = self.file.readline()
        while data:
            current = data.split()
            x = current.pop(0)
            current = ' '.join(current)
            answer[x] = answer.get(current, current)
            data = self.file.readline()

        try:
            return answer[code]
        except ValueError:
            print('invalid ICD-code')
```

When I try getting a value from it with an invalid key I get a KeyError. I don't know why this would happen since it should just go straight to a ValueError.

I do get the correct value when I use a valid key.

Can someone help me figure this out please?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why do you want to raise a `ValueError` if you want the code to continue running? Exceptions stop execution. On the other hand, if you're trying to raise a `ValueError`, where's the code for that? And why do you expect a dict to raise `ValueError` when you try to access a nonexistent key? That's what `KeyError` is for. I think you have some concepts confused, but I'm not sure what. You might want to read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for overall tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're receiving a `KeyError` rather than a `ValueError` is that Python raises a `KeyError` when you attempt to get data for a key which doesn't exist in the dictionary. Therefore, no `ValueError` is raised and your catch block is never entered. The simple solution to this would be to change the type of exception you're trying to catch to `KeyError`. However, using exception handling as execution flow is generally a bad practice so I would suggest checking if the key exists in the dictionary before retrieving it:

```
if code in answer:
    return answer[code]
else:
    raise ValueError('invalid ICD-code')
```

As an aside, I would suggest that you avoid having an open file as a field on your class. In general, it's a good idea to open files, read them and close them as one operation. Also, your code is attempting to read the data in the file every time you try to access a code from the dictionary, so this will only work for the first code. Instead, you should try this:

```
class Hippocrates:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.codes = {}
        file = open(location, "r")
        data = file.readline()
        while data:
            current = data.split()
            x = current.pop(0)
            current = ' '.join(current)
            self.codes[x] = current
            data = file.readline()
        file.close()

    def description(self, code):
        if code in self.codes:
            return self.codes[code]
        else:
            raise ValueError('invalid ICD-code')
```

Comment: so i tried using the code you gave me and it's giving me an unexpected error on the part "except ValueError:" i'm guessing this is because there was no "try:" part before it?

Comment: @Techtix Sorry, typo. It should work now

Comment: so the program that is used to check my code detects if i just print 'invalid ICD-code' so i actually need to raise a ValueError. i wish it was as easy as printing the message though

Comment: Ohh, well that's a completely different thing.

Comment: You original code was checking for a `ValueError` and printing when it found one. Instead, you need to **raise** a `ValueError` when the code isn't found.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should except KeyError for invalid keys not ValueError

so just change the try/except to:

```py
try:
    return answer[code]
except KeyError:
    print('invalid ICD-code')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `dict[key]`
then it will raise a `KeyError` if the key does not exist.
if you use `dict.get(key)` then it will return `None` if the key does not exist.

```py
class Hippocrates:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.file = open(location, "r")

    def description(self, code):
        answer = {}
        data = self.file.readline()
        while data:
            current = data.split()
            x = current.pop(0)
            current = ' '.join(current)
            answer[x] = answer.get(current, current)
            data = self.file.readline()

        try:
            return answer[code]
        except KeyError:
            print('invalid ICD-code')
```

Comment: the thing is when i try to call 2 values one after the other and the first one is not valid the code stops there since it raises a ValueError. what i want it to do is raise the ValueError for the first time i try to get a value and then try again with the next value.

Comment: `when i try to call 2 values one after the other` ?